# How to programmatically assign particular roles at user registration in Keycloak?

Tags: keycloak

When a user registers with Keycloak I want to be able to assign one of a few different roles, determined by their selections at registration, but I can't see how to achieve this - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that out of the box with Keycloak but you could implement your own Authentification provider, take a look here https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/documentation/content/server_development/topics/auth-spi.html